# Where is "scrollable stack view" in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stackview

I'm studying "scrollable stack view". I find that the sample code from Apple can directly drag and use the "scrollable stack view" control in window view.

The sample code link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/views_and_controls/organize_your_user_interface_with_a_stack_view?language=objc

Then I try to code an imitation of the "scrollable stack view", but I don't find the "scrollable stack view" in Xcode 12.

So my question is Where the "scrollable stack view" in xcode?

See the following screenshot:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/d6d74c1d-999b-412f-98dc-5feb6bd318d9
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/334e4eb5-d7e7-4dc4-821f-a972949d8bd6

Comment: There isn't any "scrollable stack view" control in the sample code.

Comment: hello, the "scrollable stack view" in "Main.storyboard". "scrollview->clipview->stackview". I have screenshot, https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/d6d74c1d-999b-412f-98dc-5feb6bd318d9      Apple's sample code, how to do it?  It is very strange.

Comment: You do exactly what you have shown in the screen shot: a stack view inside a scroll view. It isn't a scrollable stack view. It's the scroll view that is scrollable.

Comment: OK, but I mean and want to know: how to add "stack view" into "scrollview" by xcode' control list, not by coding. for example: scrollview->clipview->stackview.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Apple's instructions

> You embed a stack view inside an NSScrollView object, making the stack’s content scrollable when the user resizes the window.

1. Add a stack view
2. Choose menu Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View

Comment: Cool !!  Thank you very much.  I solve it by your hint.